# Go os.Truncate() not resetting the file cursor

Tags: go

I recently tried to use `os.Truncate` with a parameter of 0 to clear a file's contents before rewritting a modified version into it (I know that it is a very unsafe practice, but the file's contents are not important to me).

The thing that shocked me is that Truncate did not reset the file's cursor, so when I wrote back to the file I ended up with a file prefixed with a bunch of null bytes (corresponding to the size of the previous contents), unless I used `file.Seek(0, 0)` beforehand.

So my question is: is that a bug of the language, something that was forgotten during the implementation of that function, or is it on purpose and it is a desired behaviour for some mysterious reason ? What could possibly be that mysterious reason ?

I'm using go version go1.3.3 linux/amd64

Comment: Did you not read [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Truncate)? The part that says "It does not change the I/O offset."

Comment: Now you say that, I/O offset did not ring a bell at the moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is desired behaviour: the Go implementation mimics how the C works*. From the man page for [ftruncate(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate):

> The file offset is not changed.

* Technically, this is because the Go implementation [executes the `ftruncate(2)` syscall](https://golang.org/src/os/file_posix.go#L108).

Comment: Go doesn't always have the same semantics as C for these things and there is no need to refer to C library documentation. The Go documentation for [`os.File.Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Truncate) clearly states that "It does not change the I/O offset" (it's an implementation detail that they probably chose those semantics to match POSIX semantics). If Go is ported to a non-POSIX system that is either missing a truncate call or has one with different semantics, the Go library would need to avoid that and preserve it's own documented semantics.